# Is there a way to fine tune which folders inside a source are included as local files in spotify?

Tags: itunes, spotify

I have installed spotify on my mac quite some time ago, and I'm very happy with it, except for one thing: the local files feature. When I select iTunes as a source of local files, it also includes podcasts, which I don't want in spotify.

This is because in my `music/iTunes/iTunes Music/` folder, there's a folder called 'podcasts'. So now my question is, do I need to go through all my artist's directories and add them as sources, or is there a way to exclude certain subdirectories of a source?

Or is there a way to move the podcasts directory out of my music directory, and make iTunes look somewhere else for podcasts?

thx in advance.

Comment: I can answer your second question : no.

Comment: ok, thx. Then I'll have to find an other wau. I make a copy of my iTunes Media directory, and remove the podcasts, but that would require a lot of extra space, and I'd have to keep them in synch somehow.